# Bootstrap and 1 px height on col - why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone explain to me why BS has a 1px height set by default? IT was this way in 2 and 3 and I never understood why? I know it says in the comments "Prevent columns from collapsing when empty" but what browsers does it do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try and you will know: http://bootply.com/82722

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:orange;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="background-color:orange;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;min-height:0"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Comment: Some testing on Chrome, Firefox and Safari (mac) and IE 11 (PC) shows that we could change this to 0.1px and the columns would still be prevented from collapsing…


Needs testing on Mobile/Tablet devices but could be a solution if the 1px height is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
min-height: 1px;
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid