# Background-color is visible inside div with bootstrap col class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty sure that the problem has some simple solution but I am not able to find one yet other than overriding the bootstrap's default behavior which doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

The issue is simple. When I have this:

```css
#main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="main" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

You can see a black stripe on the screen even though there is not content.

After some inspection/investigation I understood that bootstrap has this default style:

> // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
>
> min-height: 1px;

I've read this [Bootstrap min height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967603/bootstrap-and-1-px-height-on-col-why) question and several other posts on the topic so it seems that it is intended to have this style.

However, and I guess this is not something uncommon, I have a page with a search functionality and when the user perform a search and select any of the results, a report should be displayed below the `search` but until this happens I have several stripes, where the content should be displayed at some point and I would like them to not be visible.

I can think of some `JS` workarounds, but wonder if it's possible to do this with pure `CSS`? I can always override the default value of `min-height` to 0 but I guess the bootstrap guys had a good reason to add this, and maybe there's a known way to avoid displaying stripes with the background color when no content is available.

Comment: You can override bootstrap CSS via an extra class and rewrite the rules with a selector with a stronger specifitie or use  !important .

Comment: @G-Cyr Yes, but I wonder if this is a good idea? I mean - probably a lot of people had faced the same problem, why would twitter devs bother to add this style if everyone would override this in order to avoid this issue with empty content and still visible parts?

Comment: the best is to use a fancy class, !important is only for test or if you are sure it will not be applied anywhere else ;)  You can also use the :empty selector to remove the background if you want to keep the min-height default value ;)

Comment: without using min-height:1px; bootstrap columns will collapse.

Comment: Just add some content inside #main and automatically the bg will appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not feel like overriding bootstrap style, then the `:empty` selector can be used to remove `background`

```css
#main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

#main:empty {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="main" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: too bad this won't work when we have space which is very common if we indent the code

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's the way it works, if a white-space stands there, then it is not empty ;)

Answer (score 2):

And idea is to hide it with a small inset `box-shadow` but you need to pay attention to transparency:

```css
.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow:0 1px 0 inset #fff;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="main col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Another idea is to rely on gradient for the background and you can adjust slightly the position:

```css
.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(black,black) 0 1px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="main col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

you can also add a `border-top` transparent and adjust the `background-clip`

```css
.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top:1px solid transparent;
  background:black;
  background-clip:padding-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="main col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: @G-Cyr yes that's why I add the *attention* :p

Comment: @G-Cyr well, I added the gradient solution .. cannot resist :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, I was also thinking about playing with the border, so your solution is pretty intuitive, however `G-Cyr`s solution is more simple and works in my case so I accepted his answer. But yours is highly appreciated too!

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap by default set min-height:1px; on his cols, so you have to set min-height:0px; to avoid this.